# How to print a list item stored in a variable?

Tags: perl

I have a list stored inside a variable and i want to print list item [2] to the console but what im doing is not working.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
my @list = ("oranges", "peaches", "apples", "grapes");
print "@list"[2];
exit 0;
```

Comment: http://perltuts.com/tutorials/quick-start/assignment-and-variables

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just try this:

```
my @list = ("oranges", "peaches", "apples", "grapes");
print $list[2];
```

Look at this [perldoc perlintro](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlintro.html)

Comment: Ah now i see, I was using this guide: http://learn.perl.org/books/beginning-perl/ but it's harder to find stuff in it.

Comment: @SkiloSkilo - See pg. 91 of that guide.